# Windows 11 uninstall Python 3.9, install 3.11.1: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using .. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Windows 11 uninstall Python 3.9, then install Python 3.11.1: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using

```py
D:\temp20221103>jupyter lab
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"  "C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\jupyter.exe" lab': The system cannot find the file specified.


D:\temp20221103>
```

[image]

Full log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/98ca21f22a5abc7b7922143054eed7e2#file-python_console-log-L92 . How to fix?

When I looking for file `jupyter-lab.exe` inside Windows Explorer, run it, it works. But this way is inconvenience.

[image]

In Windows Explorer, I still seen Python 3.9

[image]

The problem is when call command `jupyter lab`, it looks for inside wrong folder. How to fix it?

Comment: What does it give you when you type `python --version` ? (I believe that you should remove your old python path, and add new one in system path environment variable [see](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-python-path))

Comment: return Python 3.11.1

Comment: Did you remove python 3.9 from widows path ?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for where I can delete.

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
C:\Users\donhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
```

Delete folder and all sub-folder/files inside `Python39` and `Python310` . Keep folder `Python311` .